# How to sort a wild card List in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I am new to Java Streams and i want to sort a list.
The list is of type:

```
List<? extends PositionType> positions
```

I want to sort this list on the basis of a field that we get on casting each `PositionType` object to a subclass `ConvertedPosition` in ascending order.

So far i have tried this:

```
List<ConvertedPosition> sortedPositions = positions.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(((ConvertedPosition)PositionType::getPnlSpn()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But i am getting compilation error:

```
The method comparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T>) in the type Comparator is not applicable for the arguments (ConvertedPosition)
The target type of this expression must be a functional interface
```

Comment: Add the error to your question

Comment: You can't cast a method reference parameter. You'll need to make it a lambda.

Comment: "*I want to sort this list on the basis of a field that we get on casting each `PositionType` object to a subclass `ConvertedPosition` in ascending order.*" - Don't do this. What if an item in the list is not of type `ConvertedPosition`? If you need `ConvertedPosition`s then create a `List<? extends ConvertedPosition>`.

Comment: Please post the code for `PositionType` and it's sub type. Check this out on how to post a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Since you already use streams, you could `positions.stream().filter(e -> e instanceof ConvertedPositionType).map(e -> (ConvertedPositionType) e).sorted(...)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly discourage the current attempt utilizing type casting. What if there is an item in your list that is not of type `ConvertedPosition`?

If it is feasible to discard items that are not of type `ConvertedPosition`, then I would propose the following extension of the presented code:

```
List<ConvertedPosition> sortedPositions = positions.stream()
    .filter(e -> e instance ConvertedPosition) // filter out all non-ConvertedPosition items
    .map(e -> (ConvertedPosition) e)           // cast is safe due to the previous filter
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(PositionType::getPnlSpn()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[<kbd>Ideone example (1)</kbd>](http://ideone.com/e3FJNA)

If discarding non-`ConvertedPosition` items is not an option, there is also the possibility of writing some kind of converter. Yon can find a sample solution in this [<kbd>Ideone example (2)</kbd>](http://ideone.com/NqSuAh).

Comment: `.map(e -> (ConvertedPosition) e)` for casting the isntance.